# gdalwarp - correct for a slight spatial misregistration?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gml, jpeg-2000

Some Sentinel-2B band images have slight spatial misalignments as I explained on the step forum.
https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2-tci-10m-level-2-images-slight-spatial-misregistrations/14235

Furthermore the gml/jp2 band image header goes uncorrected.
I need to extract pixel values from these images as if they had been spatially aligned properly - e.g. by taking into account a 1 pixel vertical shift downwards.

Can I do this using command-line parameters to `gdalwarp` : https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html - the program I use to extract polygons of pixels?

Comment: Depending on how the images are georeferences if might be enough to extract the bands into separate images and use gdal_edit https://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html for setting the upper-left and lower-right corners `-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry:Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the dataset.`.

Comment: That's good.  While directly editing the gml in the header failed for me - using `gdal_edit.py` to do so works! thanks @user30184

Comment: Would you mind to write that as an answer with a full usage example about gdal_edit.py?

Comment: Okay @user30184 I've now added my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of **bash script** that takes an GML/JP2 image file from Sentinel-2B Level-2 10m resolution product and corrects its header. First it extracts the existing corner-coordinates using `gdalinfo` (twice); then it adds 10m to the two latitude values; then it writes the new corner coordinates back into the original image header using `gdal_edit.py`
The image in the code is second one from the step forum post at https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2-tci-10m-level-2-images-slight-spatial-misregistrations/14235

```
SUBIMG=T32SMJ_20180404T101019_TCI_10m.jp2

tmp=`gdalinfo  $SUBIMG | tr '.' ' ' | awk '/Upper Left/{ print $4" "$6}'`
uly=${tmp% *}         #first word
let ulx=10+${tmp##* } #second word plus 10

tmp=`gdalinfo  $SUBIMG | tr '.' ' ' | awk '/Lower Right/{print $4" "$6}'`
lry=${tmp% *}         #first word
let lrx=10+${tmp##* } #second word plus 10

gdal_edit.py -a_ullr $uly $ulx $lry $lrx  $SUBIMG
```

Of course the 10m change is only what I judged to be necessary by eye.